# sharing data between controllers in different pages. angular

Tags: angularjs

**I try to share data between controllers in different pages,
In the first page i change the data, and is changing!.
but in the second page the default values are shown.**

The factory:

```
app.factory('Sponsor',function(){

    var name='XXX';
    var order=1

    return {
        getName: function () {
            return name;
        },
        getOrder: function () {
            return order;
        },
        setSponsor:function (order1,name1) {
            order=order1;
            name=name1;
            return name;
        }
    };
})
```

In the first page:

```
app.controller('sponsors', function($scope,$http,Sponsor) {
...
     $scope.sponsorSelect=Sponsor.getName;
     $scope.sponsorSelect=Sponsor.setSponsor(order,name);
     window.open('./../hhh/kkk.html');
}
```

In the second

```
app.controller('studyManagerControll', function($scope,$http,Sponsor)
{
...
$scope.sponsor=Sponsor.getName;
}
```

What can i do to share the data successfully?

**p.s

I have try: service and return object: sponsor={}.. sponsor.get..{} and return sponsor.**

Comment: Do you mean `$scope.sponsor = Sponsor.getName();` in the second controller?

Comment: yes, in HTML code it look :{{sponsor()}}

Comment: Do you have like another angular app in `window.open('./../hhh/kkk.html');`?

Comment: yes, this page open successfully! the problem is with the sharing data, it shown the default data. like it not update

Comment: Well obviously there can be no sharing. You have to use some persistence layer, like localStorage.

Comment: How can i work with localStorage or something like this. and why it not share with the factory between some pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your getname is not property it is a method you first need to attach braces with it

like

```
 $scope.sponsor=Sponsor.getName();
```

Comment: In HTML code i write {{sponsor()}}. and i have try the two ways